# Claims not persisting in Session Token

Tags: caching, session-cookies, claims-based-identity, claims

Have seen Dominick Baier's videos on Pluralsight and most of this I got from there. I'm trying to do a claims transformation in .net 4.5, MVC. After a lot of messing around I can get the claims transformed, but can't get them to persist. If I just have it run my ClaimsTransformer every time no problem, but this is hitting a database so I want to cache these.

So here's what I did

```
  class ClaimsTransformer : ClaimsAuthenticationManager
  {
    public override ClaimsPrincipal Authenticate(string resourceName, ClaimsPrincipal incomingPrincipal)
    {
      if (!incomingPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
      {
        return base.Authenticate(resourceName, incomingPrincipal);
      }

      ClaimsPrincipal transformedPrincipal = incomingPrincipal;
```

I then perform some database access add new claims to transformedPrincipal. Then create a new principal (probably don't need this additional instantiation but others seemed to do it), write this out:

```
 ClaimsPrincipal newClaimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(transformedPrincipal.Claims, "ApplicationCookie"));

  if (HttpContext.Current != null)
  {
    // this caches the transformed claims
    var sessionToken = new SessionSecurityToken(newClaimsPrincipal, TimeSpan.FromHours(8));
    FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(sessionToken);
  }
  return newClaimsPrincipal;
```

I can see the new claims here in newClaimsPrincipal. To force the transformation to get called I am using ClaimsTransformationHttpModule from the ThinkTecture guys and can verify that this code gets run:

```
    context.User = transformedPrincipal;
    HttpContext.Current.User = transformedPrincipal;
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = transformedPrincipal;
```

And my additional claims are part of the transformedPrincipal.

So looks fine - but when subsequent requests come in I don't have the additional claims. ClaimsTransformer is not called, as expected, but I only have the initial set of claims - not those added by my transformation.

After logging out, my additional claims are persisted. This is using the new Visual Studio 2013 basic MVC template with Identity 2.0etc.

What I think is happening is the login runs first:

```
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

and this writes the authentication cookie, before my claims are transformed. Following this my claimstransformer runs and writes its own authorization cookie so now I have two. When I logout the first one's claims are lost and not the second one's claims become active.

Am confused.com.

Thanks
Ray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are mixing the two architectures.

- ClaimsAuthenticationManager and FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule are the .NET 4.5 way of doing things. Also called the WIF method.
- SignInManager is OWIN.

Indeed don't use the WIF things in this way when you are using OWIN.

This should clarify/solve half your problem. Now you still need a ClaimsTransform in OWIN. Some filter should do it and then persist it in the OWIN identity Cookie (haven't yet done it myself).

Comment: Hey there thanks for that. Got me on the right track and I found I can set up something up which will run the OWin sign takes place. You have to do this when you set up the cookie
:OnResponseSignIn = ctx =>
                    {
                      ctx.Identity = TransformClaims(ctx.Identity);
                    }